# MySQL record average druing weekday and each hour

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently getting a count grouped by hour and week day of calls made:

```
SELECT HOUR(creationtimestamp), dayname(creationtimestamp), count(*)
FROM cdrdb.session
WHERE DATE_SUB(creationtimestamp,INTERVAL 1 HOUR) And 
creationtimestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY HOUR(creationtimestamp);
```

Which returns:

```
0   Monday  23
0   Tuesday 96
0   Wednesday   85
0   Thursday    76
0   Friday  114
0   Saturday    47
0   Sunday  32
1   Monday  2
1   Tuesday 20
1   Wednesday   19
1   Thursday    16
1   Friday  31
1   Saturday    9
1   Sunday  6
2   Monday  13
2   Tuesday 18
2   Wednesday   5
2   Thursday    5
2   Friday  8
```

And this continues to hour 23 But this isn't exactly what I'm aiming to get.

I'd like to have around 60 results after all is said and done, on average of records for hours 7 am to 6 pm
so I'd  have a row for each hour of monday through friday with the average number of records in that time frame.

Maybe it would look more like

```
Monday | 7:00 | 89
Monday | 8:00 | 53
Monday | 9:00 | 53
...
Tuesday | 8:00 | 53
```

How would I change my grouping for this

UPDATE QUERY:

Correct number of hours and days, but averages may not be right. Trying to get average calls for every monday from 8 to 859 am, etc.

```
SELECT 
dayname(creationtimestamp) as day, 
HOUR(creationtimestamp) as Hour, 
(sum(callsIN/ 60) * 100 as averageCalls,
(sum(callsMissed)/sum(callsIN) * 100 as averageMissedCalls
  FROM session s
    WHERE (creationtimestamp >= '2018-01-01' AND creationtimestamp < now())
  and WEEKDAY(creationtimestamp) BETWEEN 0 AND 4
  AND HOUR(creationtimestamp) between  7 and 18 
  AND finallycalledpartyno IN ( 7276,7314,7295,7306,7357,7200,7218,7247,7331,7255,7330,7000,7215,7240,7358,7312)
  GROUP BY dayname(creationtimestamp),  HOUR(creationtimestamp)
  order by dayofweek(creationtimestamp), hour asc;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use for group by dayname(creationtimestamp),  HOUR(creationtimestamp)  and limit to 60 the result

```
  SELECT HOUR(creationtimestamp), dayname(creationtimestamp), count(*)
  FROM cdrdb.session
  WHERE DATE_SUB(creationtimestamp,INTERVAL 1 HOUR) And 
  creationtimestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  AND HOUR(creationtimestamp) between  7 and 18 
  GROUP BY dayname(creationtimestamp),  HOUR(creationtimestamp) 
  ORDER BY dayname(creationtimestamp),  HOUR(creationtimestamp)  limit 60;
```

Comment: Instead of limit to 60, could I just change this to only get records from the first of the year on monday through friday from 7am to 6 pm?

Comment: In other words, MONDAY 0800 560, would mean 560 average records on mondays between 800 and 859

Comment: So I swould change Date sub to account for every weekday from the first of the year?

Comment: your comment is not clear ..  .. if you need  another date range obviuosly you can change the date related part of the query

Comment: I've changed it to go from 2018-01-01 to now, but I'm trying to see if it's averaging for every monday, tuesday, etc.

Comment: Can you see my updated query? I'm getting 60 rows of correct days and times but is this affecting my averages? They seem high but I'm trying to get my two averages for "Each day of week at that hour within date range"